# Xamarin.Android AOT .so.dll-files are still referencing methods when inspecting with Mac Terminal

Tags: dll, xamarin.android, aot

I'm currently testing some features about Xamarin Android AOT. The AOT is working well, except for one criteria.
On Mac, when using terminal and the command "objdump -t libaot-AnyNameOfOwnWritten.dll.so", I can still see references to methods used.
Is there a way to remove these references?

My Droid.csproj configuration:

```
    <DebugSymbols>false</DebugSymbols>
    <AotAssemblies>True</AotAssemblies>
    <EnableProguard>True</EnableProguard>
    <EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>True</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>
    <AndroidSupportedAbis>armeabi-v7a;arm64-v8a</AndroidSupportedAbis>
    <AndroidAotAdditionalArguments>nodebug,no-write-symbols</AndroidAotAdditionalArguments>
    <AndroidAotMode>Normal</AndroidAotMode>
    <EnableLLVM>True</EnableLLVM>
    <BundleAssemblies>True</BundleAssemblies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated the Android NDK to the latest version and it worked.